# can't install open edx in windows 7 ultimate

Tags: windows, curl, vagrant

i want to install open edx fullstack in windows 7 ultimate , i install first of all

```
VirtualBox >= 4.3.12
Vagrant >= 1.5.3
```

and also curl 
and when i would like install open edx in prompt commande :

```
mkdir fullstack
cd fullstack
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/edx/configuration/master/vagrant/release/fullstack/Vagrantfile > Vagrantfile
vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostsupdater
vagrant up
```

i found this error  after vagrant up

```
 C:\Users\khaoula\edx_aspen>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'aspen-fullstack-1' could not be found. Attempting to find and
install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Adding box 'aspen-fullstack-1' (v0) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: http://files.edx.org/vagrant-images/20141028-aspen-ful
lstack-1.box
    default: Progress: 0% (Rate: 16462/s, Estimated time remaining: 72:23:58)
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

transfer closed with 2992127314 bytes remaining to read
```

thanks for helping me

Comment: seems your network is not stable. the [box file](http://files.edx.org/vagrant-images/20141028-aspen-fullstack-1.box) is 2.8GB, it takes long time to download and clearly your network is not good enough to finish the downloading.

Answer (score 1):

**Install Vagrant and Virtual Box-**

**create project folder-**

```
mkdir testapp
```

**Create Vagrant Instance-**

```
vagrant init testapp
```

**Add Box(Ubuntu 14.04)**
You can download box from floolowing link

```
http://hashicorp-files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box
```

**Add vagrant box**

```
vagrant box add --NAME testapp c://downloads/precise64.box
```

**Once your box added**

```
vagrant up
```

if any errors ocoured-
disable apache,skype,IIS,Elascticsearch services..

**Run Box**

```
vagrant ssh
```

once you login to Ubuntu inside virtual box-

**In Terminal-**

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo reboot
```

after reboot use vagrant ssh again

**Install EDX**

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/edx/configuration/master/util/install/vagrant.sh -O - | bash
```